# Treeview not stretching

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a simple application with a Treeview and a main content area in a grid. The grid has a gridsplitter to resize, but this does not resize the Treeview.

[image]

I have read this is a bug,

> but what is the simplest way to resize the Treeview?

```
<Window x:Class="TestGridSplitter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />                              
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView Grid.Column="0">
        <TreeViewItem>
            My Treeview
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2">
        Main Content Area
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Setting horizontal alignment or contentalignment to Stretch, does not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moreover, it is necessary to set other properties of `GridSplitter` such as `ResizeDirection="Columns"` and `ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"` properties. For example:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5" ResizeDirection="Columns"  
                                 ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the next approach:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="#feca00">
        <TextBlock FontSize="35" Foreground="#58290A" TextWrapping="Wrap">
          Left Hand Side
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <GridSplitter Width="4" Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

    <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="#58290A" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="10">
        <TextBlock FontSize="25" Foreground="#FECA00" TextWrapping="Wrap">
          Right Hand Side
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```